# Prediction trajectory line with matter.js

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am building my first little matter.js game - PartyGolf. The gameplayer is similar to Angry Birds. I want to show a prediction trajectory line to show where the ball will go, but I could not find how it is possible in matter.js

I tried with Phaser game framework, but it's not workin with matter.js. For example http://bl.ocks.org/joyrexus/11220109

```
render() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.context.drawImage(this.background, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height / 2);
    for (let i = 0, len = this.boundaries.length; i < len; i++) {
        this.context.beginPath();
        let vertices = this.boundaries[i].body.vertices;
        this.context.moveTo(vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y);
        for (let j = 1; j < vertices.length; j++) {
            this.context.lineTo(vertices[j].x, vertices[j].y);
        }
        this.context.lineTo(vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y);
        this.context.fillStyle = '#000';
        this.context.fill();
        this.context.stroke();
        this.context.closePath();
    }

    for (let i = 0, len = this.balls.length; i < len; i++) {
        let ball = this.balls[i];
        ball.addTrailPoint(ball.body.position.x, ball.body.position.y);

        this.context.lineWidth = ball.radius * 2;
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.lineCap = 'round';
        this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
        this.context.moveTo(ball.trailPoints[0][0], ball.trailPoints[0][1]);
        this.context.globalAlpha = 0.3;
        this.context.strokeStyle = ball.color;
        for (let j = 1, len = ball.trailPoints.length; j < len; j++) {
            this.context.lineTo(ball.trailPoints[j][0], ball.trailPoints[j][1]);
        }
        this.context.stroke();
        this.context.closePath();
        this.context.lineWidth = 1;
        this.context.globalAlpha = 1;

        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(ball.body.position.x, ball.body.position.y, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        this.context.lineWidth = 2;
        this.context.fillStyle = ball.color;
        this.context.strokeStyle = '#000';
        this.context.fill();
        this.context.stroke();
        this.context.closePath();
    }

    this.context.lineWidth = 0;
    this.context.strokeStyle = '#000';

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
}

run() {
    this.render()
}
```

I expect only with matter.js to show prediction line.

Comment: This could be done with vectors. The angle of aim and speed. You'll have to study vectors, break the motion in components and then It'll be very easy to predict where the projectile is going to go

Comment: This is a little physics but can be done using some paperwork to achieve good results. Check [this article on this motion](https://www.toppr.com/guides/physics/motion-in-a-plane/projectile-motion/) To get code [check this thread on github](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/584) Even they are using vectors